# how can i fix this error about webdriver?

Tags: php, laravel, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am using laravel Framework in PHP and studying webdriver but recently i get a errors, 
Can you look at my errors?

i'am Installed facebook / webdriver from https://packagist.org and i executed in git bash, like this.

```
composer require facebook / webdriver
```

After entering the Java web and installing Java and then download the selenium-server-standalone-3.14.0 and put it in the laravel myproject folder

I have executed code below in git bash.

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.14.0.jar
```

I then set the url on the laravel project and wrote the example code below on the controller

```
<?php

namespace Facebook\WebDriver;
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\DesiredCapabilities;
use Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\RemoteWebDriver;


class TestController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        require_once('../vendor/autoload.php');
        // start Chrome with 5 second timeout
        $host = 'http://localhost:4444'; // this is the default
        $capabilities = DesiredCapabilities::chrome();
        $driver = RemoteWebDriver::create($host, $capabilities, 5000);
        // navigate to 'http://www.seleniumhq.org/'
        $driver->get('https://www.seleniumhq.org/');
        // adding cookie
        $driver->manage()->deleteAllCookies();
        $cookie = new Cookie('cookie_name', 'cookie_value');
        $driver->manage()->addCookie($cookie);
        $cookies = $driver->manage()->getCookies();
        print_r($cookies);
        // click the link 'About'
        $link = $driver->findElement(
        WebDriverBy::id('menu_about')
        );
        $link->click();
        // wait until the page is loaded
        $driver->wait()->until(
        WebDriverExpectedCondition::titleContains('About')
        );
        // print the title of the current page
        echo "The title is '" . $driver->getTitle() . "'\n";
        // print the URI of the current page
        echo "The current URI is '" . $driver->getCurrentURL() . "'\n";
        // write 'php' in the search box
        $driver->findElement(WebDriverBy::id('q'))
        ->sendKeys('php') // fill the search box
        ->submit(); // submit the whole form
        // wait at most 10 seconds until at least one result is shown
        $driver->wait(10)->until(
            WebDriverExpectedCondition::presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy(
            WebDriverBy::className('gsc-result')
        )
        );
        // close the browser
        $driver->quit();
}
```

}

Finally, I accessed the browser and got the following error

```
JSON decoding of remote response failed. Error code: 4 The response:
```

Could you give me some advice on why the error occurred?

my english is very low level. so please Understand my mistake and thank for reading this post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check this

[php-webdriver/issues/350](https://github.com/facebook/php-webdriver/issues/350)

[php-webdriver/issues/347](https://github.com/facebook/php-webdriver/issues/347)

Maybe you need to set the host to something like -- 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub' -- or maybe is an issue with the library.

Also you can try to access the selenium server when is started and try to debug it.

Thanks,